# Bootstrap confirmation deja de funcionar cuando se cambia de pagina de una tabla (paginacion 5 ítem)

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-table

Estoy insertando dinámicamente ítem a una tabla que usa [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) con paginacion de 5 ítems; en una de las columnas hay una opción para eliminar el ítem a su vez esta opción de eliminar usa [bootstrap-confirmation](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/) que solicita la confirmación para eliminar con las opciones **SI** o **NO**.

Hasta acá todo bien, el conflicto se genera si se agregan mas de 5 ítems y el usuario cambia a otra pagina, deja de funcionar la petición de confirmación **bootstrap-confirmation**

Así inserto las filas en la tabla:

```
    var fila = [];
    fila.push({
        id: id_fila,
        codProducto: $('#codProducto').val(),

        opcion: '<a class="btn btn-xs red uppercase" data-toggle="confirmation"' +
        'data-placement="top" data-original-title="" data-id="' + id_fila + '"' +
        'data-singleton="true" title="¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar?">' +
        '<i class="fa fa-remove tooltip-text" title="Eliminar ítem"></i></a>'
    });
    $("#tProductos").bootstrapTable('prepend', fila);
    $('.tooltip-text').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        btnOkLabel: "SI",
        btnCancelLabel: "NO",
        btnOkClass: "btn green-jungle",
        btnCancelClass: "btn red"
    }).on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', eliminarProducto);
```

-- Esta es la función que se llama al presionar si en la confirmación para eliminar:

```
function eliminarProducto(event) {
    var attr = $(event.currentTarget);
    var id = attr.data('id');
    $("#tProductos").bootstrapTable('removeByUniqueId', id);
    $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        btnOkLabel: "SI",
        btnCancelLabel: "NO",
        btnOkClass: "btn green-jungle",
        btnCancelClass: "btn red"
    }).on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', eliminarProducto);
}
```

Así se ve funcionando la confirmación para eliminar estando en la pagina 1 de la tabla:

[image: boostrap-confirmation funcional pagina 1]

Acá cuando muevo a la pagina 2 y ya no funciona el confirmation:

[image: no despliega el mensaje de confirmación]

```js
$(function () {
  id_fila = 0;
});
function eliminarProducto(event) {
    var attr = $(event.currentTarget);
    var id = attr.data('id');
    $("#tProductos").bootstrapTable('removeByUniqueId', id);
    $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        btnOkLabel: "SI",
        btnCancelLabel: "NO",
        btnOkClass: "btn btn-primary",
        btnCancelClass: "btn btn-danger"
    }).on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', eliminarProducto);
}
$("#aggProducto").click(function() {
    var fila = [];
    fila.push({
      id: id_fila,
      codProducto: "000",
      opcion: '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger uppercase" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="top" data-original-title="" data-id="' + id_fila + '" data-singleton="true" title="¿Esta seguro que desea eliminar?"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>x</a>',
      articulo: "articulo"
  });
  $("#tProductos").bootstrapTable('prepend', fila);
  $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
      rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
      btnOkLabel: "SI",
      btnCancelLabel: "NO",
      btnOkClass: "btn btn-primary",
      btnCancelClass: "btn btn-danger"
  }).on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', eliminarProducto);
  id_fila++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.1/locale/bootstrap-table-es-ES.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>


<table id="tProductos" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-footer table-condensed" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-id-field="id" data-page-size="5" data-unique-id="id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-visible="false"></th>
            <th data-field="codProducto" data-visible="false"></th>
            <th class="centered" data-field="opcion" data-width="10%">Opciones</th>
            <th data-field="articulo" data-width="90%">Artículo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a id="aggProducto" title="Agregar producto" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Agregar Producto</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que no todos los botones de todas las páginas de tu tabla se encuentran en el `DOM`, entonces para adjuntar el evento a algún selector tendrías que hacerlo que aplique en el `DOM` en general, y no sólo a los que actualmente se encuentran en el `DOM`, en jQuery, cuando adjuntas un evento a elementos dinámicos, sería de la siguiente forma, por ejemplo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tu-clase', function(e){
   //Aquí lo que va a ejecutar el evento
});
```

En tu caso, el plugin que manejas, tiene una opción para establecer el selector y la raíz del selector, entonces podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
$('body').confirmation({
   rootSelector: 'body',
   selector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
   // aquí las otras opciones
});
```

Con esto debería de funcionar para elementos creados dinámicamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y la respuesta, funciona muy bien.